# Click function in ng2-smart-table column

Tags: angular, onclick, click, ng2-smart-table

I have been trying to get a click function to be included in a ng2-smart-table column. It seems angular (click) event and javascipt "onclick" do not get rendered in the table. The code is below

```
public settings = {
selectMode: 'single',  //single|multi
hideHeader: false,
hideSubHeader: false,
actions: {
  columnTitle: 'Actions',
  add: false,
  edit: false, // true,
  delete: false, // true,
  custom: false
},
noDataMessage: 'No data found',
columns: {
  IsComplete: {
    title:'Status',
    type:'html',
    filter: false,        
    valuePrepareFunction: (value) => {
      // return value===true ? 'Complete' : 'Pending';
      if(value===true){
        return  '<div class="text-nowrap text-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"> Complete</i></div>'; //  Complete';
        //return  'Complete';
      } else {
        //return  'Pending';
        return  '<div class="text-nowrap text-warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Pending</div>'; //  Pending';
      }
    }
  },
  DateCreated: {
    title: 'Date created',
    type: 'string',
    filter: true,
    valuePrepareFunction: (date) => {
      var raw = new Date(date);
      var formatted = new DatePipe('en-EN').transform(raw, 'dd MMM yyyy');
      return formatted;
    }
  },      
  MemberName: {
    title: 'Member',
    type: 'string',
    filter: true
  },
  Start: {
    title: 'Start date',
    type: 'string',
    filter: false,
    valuePrepareFunction: (date) => {
      var raw = new Date(date);
      var formatted = new DatePipe('en-EN').transform(raw, 'dd MMM yyyy');
      return formatted;
    }
  },
  End: {
    title: 'End date',
    type: 'string',
    filter: false,
    valuePrepareFunction: (date) => {
      var raw = new Date(date);
      var formatted = new DatePipe('en-EN').transform(raw, 'dd MMM yyyy');
      return formatted;
    }
  },
  OrderId: {
    title: 'Details',
    type: 'html',
    filter: false,
    valuePrepareFunction: (OrderId) => {
      return  '<a onclick="onCustom($event)" href="/pages/order/' + OrderId + '"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> view</a>'; //  Complete';
    }
  }
```

The column of interest is "OrderId" event to be fired is below, however I also want the user to be able to right-click the link and select open new tab, etc, hence the link as well as the click function.

```
onCustom(event) { this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/order/' + event.data.OrderId); }
```

Using dev tools I see that the onclick or (click) is ignored and all I get is the  link;

```
<a href="/pages/order/411"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> view</a>
```

**Update:** I have also thought of using a custom action column to take advantage of the "onCustom()"function called but have not been able to get valuePrepareFunction to be rendered (only get "title" property rendering) or reference the row data in the "title" property like so.

```
custom: [{
name: 'view',
title: 'View ',
type: 'html',
valuePrepareFunction:(row)=>{
  return `<a title="See Detail Product "href="Your api key or something/${row.OrderId}"> <i class="ion-edit"></i></a>`
},
```

}
],

Answer (score 4):

When you used `valuePrepareFunction` pass type=`custom`. Try with `custom` as a type instead of `html`

**Update**

You can user `renderComponent` feature.

```
type: 'custom',
valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
   return row.columnName;
},
renderComponent: NewComponent,
```

Hear you have to make a one component and then pass in `renderComponent`.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component,Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewCell } from 'ng2-smart-table';

@Component({
 selector: '',
 templateUrl: '',
 styleUrls: ['']
})
export class NewComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {
  renderValue: string;
  @Input() value: string | number;
  @Input() rowData: any;

  constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.renderValue = this.value.toString();
 }

 clicked(name){
   console.log(name);
 }

}
```

**html file**

```
<span (click)="clicked(renderValue)">{{renderValue}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin. If it was possible to include the row data in the custom type this would allow me to have both the "onCustom" event and include a "<a href=somelink/{{rowdata.value}}" link, but I have been unable to get a row value in the custom column. The challenge is that I can get a "this.router.navigateByUrl" call but not a link which someone can right click and "open link in new tab". Also valuePrepareFunction does not seem to fire--when I use a custom type the column does not render at all (blank)

Comment: I have update my answer. I have add my working code.

Comment: Is it possible to disable a custom action link based on row data? If not then how this table is called smart table I don't understand

Comment: @SayedUzZaman Yes it's possible to disable the column row action link based on row data. It's also one of the reason to address this table as a Smart Table.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do it? I have created 3 custom action, edit, view, delete. I want to disable edit operation based on my row data. If row contains edited, then I need to disable the edit button. How should I do it?

Comment: @SayedUzZaman Have you tried like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52781288/8612835

Comment: I will try this out and will post an update. thank you.

Comment: @SayedUzZaman Sure, Welcome. Happy to help you. :)