# Conditionally add custom button in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

In ng2-smart-table, I want a button 'Start' or 'End' which I am showing conditionally. How can I do this?
I am having a condition If that's true, then I want to show 'Start' button and if it is false, then I want to show 'End' button. Also, I need to perform something if a user clicks these buttons.

```
tableSettings = {
actions: false,
columns: {
  code: {
    title: 'Code'
  },
  first_name: {
    title: 'First Name'
  },
  last_name: {
    title: 'Last Name'
  },
  email_id: {
    title: 'Email'
  },
  start_time: {
    title: 'Start Time',
    type: 'date',
    valuePrepareFunction: (date) => { 
      return this.renderDateTime(date); 
    }
  },
  end_time: {
    title: 'End Time',
    type: 'date',
    valuePrepareFunction: (date) => {
      return this.renderDateTime(date); 
    }
  },
  start: {
    title: 'Start/End',
    type: 'html',
    valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
      return `<button *ng-If="renderButton(row) === 'Start'" (click)="startTest()">Start</button>`; 
    }
  }
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I gave one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54396493/8612835) on this `valuePrepareFunction`. This may help you.